# How to Set UserNames in Ansible Dynamic Inventory EC2

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have a simple Ansible dynamic inventory for AWS servers that looks like this.

```
---
plugin: aws_ec2

regions:
  - eu-west-2

keyed_groups:
  - key: tags.Name

hostnames:
# A list in order of precedence for hostname variables.
  - ip-address


 compose:
     ansible_host: _Applications_
     ansible_user: "'ubuntu'"
```

This works fine, except that I also have another instance that's Redhat.

Which means that when I try to do a simple `ping` command on all the hosts, it fails as the username `ubuntu` is only valid on one of the servers.

Is there a way to set group my inventory file so that I can add in the `ec2-user` username for a specific group maybe based on it's tag or something else.

I could do this easily with my static inventory but I'm not sure how to do this with a dynamic inventory.

I've tried setting my Ansible inventory as an environment variable

`export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=~/Users/inventory`

And placed my `aws_ec2.yaml`in the inventory directory along with a group vars directory containing my different groups with default usernames in each of the different groups

```
username: ubuntu
```

```
username: ec2-user
```

and then setting my inventory file as such

```
compose:
   ansible_user: "{{ username }}"
```

But when Ansible tries to connect, it's using an `admin` username and not what's set in my group vars.

Is there a way to set the different usernames needed to connect to the different type of servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the example for the [constructed](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/constructed_inventory.html#examples) plugin, you can use the `keyed_group` feature to create groups by `ansible_distribution`:

```
keyed_groups:
    # this creates a group per distro (distro_CentOS, distro_Debian) and assigns the hosts that have matching values to it,
    # using the default separator "_"
    - prefix: distro
      key: ansible_distribution
```

And then set `ansible_user` inside `groups_vars/distro_Ubuntu.yaml` and `group_vars/distro_RedHat.yaml`.

Also from the documentation, this requires fact caching to operate (because otherwise Ansible doesn't know the value of `ansible_distribution` at the time it's processing the `keyed_groups` setting).

---

I don't have access to AWS at the moment, but here's how I'm testing everything locally.  Given an inventory that looks like:

```
$ tree inventory
inventory/
├── 00-hosts.yaml
└── 10-constructed.yaml
```

Where `inventory/00-hosts.yaml` looks like:

```
all:
  hosts:
    host0:
      ansible_host: localhost
```

And `inventory/10-constructed.yaml` looks like:

```
plugin: constructed
strict: false
groups:
  ipmi_hosts: ipmi_host|default(false)
keyed_groups:
  - prefix: "distro"
    key: ansible_distribution
```

And `ansible.cfg` looks like:

```
[defaults]
inventory = inventory
enable_plugins = constructed

gathering = smart
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = ./.facts
```

The first time I run this playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: group_names
```

The output of the debug task is:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host0] => {
    "group_names": [
        "ungrouped"
    ]
}
```

But because of the fact gathering and caching performed by the previous playbook run, the second time I run it the output is:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host0] => {
    "group_names": [
        "distro_Fedora"
    ]
}
```

Similarly, before the first playbook run `ansible-inventory --graph` outputs:

```
@all:
  |--@ungrouped:
  |  |--host0
```

But after running the playbook once, I get:

```
@all:
  |--@distro_Fedora:
  |  |--host0
  |--@ungrouped:
```

---

I've bundled this all into [an example repository](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-70870752/tree/main).

Comment: I tried this. But I'm struggling to work it out. When I run the `ansible-inventory --graph` to see what my inventory looks like, it comes back blank

Comment: Thanks a lot Larsks